# How to pass in initial value in Form Fields after post?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

In my application views i have three Apply buttons, hence three POSTS...
1st i select from a given choice an object.
2nd for the selected object I upload a file which is parsed withing second POST and returns some calculated values.
These values I want to pass into my next request.POST as initial values to certain fields in a form I have.
Help required...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Form Wizard: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" name="stuff" value="some_data_from_step_2">
```